# Command CMD in Windows

Tags: cmd.exe, batch-rename

How can I make this:

[image]

Into this:

[image]

Using CMD commands.

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i still didnt try nothing.
i just dont know what to do and how

Comment: Did you try to Google "rename multiple files with cmd"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use rename in combination with Wildcards. For example ren DSC* pirateday*

Comment: This doesn't work for me as you describe... **"A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found."** error message pops up during the **`REN`** operation in the format as in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your needs.

You can paste the following code directly into the CMD Window.

However first make sure your path to the pictures is edited from the below example to be correct for you before pasting it into the CMD prompt.

```
SETLOCAL
SET "_YourPath=C:\Path\To\Files\"
SET "_NewNamePart1=Pirateday ("
SET "_NewNamePart2=)"
FOR /R "%_YourPath%" %A (DSC_*.jpg) DO @(
    FOR /F "Tokens=* Delims=DSC_0" %a IN ("%~nA") DO @(
        IF NOT EXIST "%~dpA%_NewNamePart1%%~a%_NewNamePart2%%~xA" (
            MOVE /Y "%~fA" "%~dpA%_NewNamePart1%%~a%_NewNamePart2%%~xA"
        ) ELSE (
            MOVE /Y "%~fA" "%~dpA%_NewNamePart1%%~a%_NewNamePart2% %Time::=.%%~xA"
        )
    )
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Note, this also checks for a name which may already exist, and if found it will rename the photo with the time appended to the name.

Comment: I haven’t tried this, but, from reading it, it appears to rename each file so the beginning changes and a right parenthesis is added, but the number is left untouched.   But, if you look closely at the question, you’ll see that it is asking for a one-up number — e.g., there is no `DSC_0008`, but `DSC_0009` gets renamed to `Pirateday (8)`.   This is not a bad answer, but we prefer answers that explain what they are doing in enough detail that they *say* what the code is doing.

Comment: Ahh, cool, my experience on Stack Exchange has been that if the answer is verbose or handles situations not explicitly asked for even if implicitly needed it isn't well received.  I'd be happy to write a little more explanation.  And you're right, the picture does show them numbered in numerical order not the original order, although this was not obvious based on the text, my bad.  The code could be amended for that scenario Instead.  And thanks, glad you appreciate the effort :)

Comment: Well, we are not a hive mind; we are several thousand individual people, and we don’t all respond the same way.